# Boundedness of solution operator

Tags: analysis, operator-theory, heat-equation

when dealing with the linear heat equation
\begin{align*}
\partial_t u &= \partial_{xx} u, \quad 0<x<l, 0<t<T\\
\partial_x u(0,t) &= \partial_x u(l,t) = 0, \quad 0<t<T\\
u(x,0) &= g(x), \quad 0<x<l
\end{align*}

one can define the corresponding solution operator $T:L^2(0,l) \rightarrow L^2(0,T;H^1(0,l)), g(x) \mapsto u(x,t)$. How can I show that this operator is bounded, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^T \lVert u\rVert_{H^1(0,l)} dt \leq C \int_0^l \lvert g(x) \rvert^2 dx
\end{align*}
I tried to reformulate the left side
\begin{align*}
\int_0^T  \lVert u\rVert_{H^1(0,l)} dt = \int_0^T \lVert u \rVert_{L^2(0,l)}+ \lVert \partial_x u \rVert_{L^2(0,l)} dt
\end{align*}
but I am stuck immediately. Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Take the derivative in time of the $L^2$ norm ;)

Comment: @LL3.14, thanks for your reply, but what do you mean?

Comment: @LL3.14, oh did you mean that I forgot to include the derivative in time of the $L^2$ norm when I tried to reformulate the left side in the last line of computation?

Comment: No, I was saying that you can try to compute $\partial_t \int |u|^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It holds
$$
\partial_t \int_0^l |u|^2 = \int_0^l 2\,u \,\partial_tu = 2 \int_0^l u \,\partial_{xx}u
$$
hence, integrating by parts and using the fact that $\partial_x u = 0$ at $x=0$ and $x=l$,
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\partial_t \int_0^l |u|^2 = -2 \int_0^l |\partial_{x}u|^2.
$$
In particular, $\|u\|_{L^2}$ is decreasing in time so
$$\tag{2}\label{2}
\int_0^T \|u(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2}^2\,\mathrm d t \leq \int_0^T \|g\|_{L^2}^2\,\mathrm d t \leq T\,\|g\|_{L^2}^2.
$$
Taking the integral in time of Inequality \eqref{1} yields
$$
\int_0^l |u(T,x)|^2\,\mathrm d x - \int_0^l |u(0,x)|^2\,\mathrm d x =  -2 \int_0^T\!\!\!\int_0^l |\partial_{x}u(t,x)|^2\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d t,
$$
which implies
$$
2 \int_0^T \|\partial_{x}u(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(0,l)}^2\,\mathrm d t \leq \|g\|_{L^2(0,l)}^2.
$$
Combining this inequality with Equation \eqref{2}, leads to
$$
\|u(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2((0,T),H^1(0,l))}^2 \leq \left(T + \tfrac{1}{2}\right) \|g\|_{L^2(0,l)}^2.
$$

Comment: @ LL3.14, thanks so much for your detailed answer! Can I ask you another topic regarding the topic?  We have shown that the solution operator is bounded when $u$ is a strong solution of the PDE. What does change, when we assume that $u$ is a weak solution?

Comment: Nothing changes, if your initial data is in $L^2$, then the solution will have the $L^2H^1$ regularity. You can prove it by approximating your weak solution by smooth functions.